# IOS-Objective c Project

Tags: ios, objective-c

While I'm running a `Simulator` it will works fine at the first time but when we repeat to the second time it occurs an error:

> launch service error 0.

Tested `Simulators` `4s, 5, 5s, 6, 6s, 6s plus`.

Comment: Clean your `Drived Data`, reset your simulator, clean your project and restart x_code. Now Build your project first and then run.

Comment: i tried to comment ans but there was many points to suggest, kindly check then let's know your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a issue of your apps bundle ID which is handled later after installing app over simulator.

Try with some solutions:

1. try cleaning the build folder `shift + command + option + k`.
2. try by cleaning a derived data located inside `/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`.
3. try by Reset content settings of `simulator` by selecting it see image.

   [image]

Hope this helps.